# OpenCv Cropping issue

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am new to openCV. I am trying to crop an image but the code that I have written is not cropping it. Please help me out. I got the region of my interest but when I try to copy it it copies the whole image not only the region of interest

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>


CvMemStorage * st = 0;
CvHaarClassifierCascade * hcc= 0;
char * path =  "C:/Users/Gardezi/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/AIMRL/AIMRL/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";



bool startDetection(IplImage * img)
{   
int i ;
cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img) , img->depth , img->nChannels );
CvPoint pt1 , pt2;
IplImage * f ;
if (hcc)
{
        CvSeq * face = cvHaarDetectObjects(img , hcc , st , 1.1  , 2 , CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING , cvSize(40  , 40 ) );


    //Face to Data Base 

    for (i = 0 ;i <  (face? face->total : 0 ) ; i++)
    {
        CvRect * r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(face , i );
        pt1.x = r->x; 
        pt1.y = r->y;
        pt2.x = r->x + r->width;
        pt2.y = r->y + r->height;

    cvRectangle(img , pt1 , pt2 , CV_RGB(255, 0 , 0) , 3 , 8 , 0); 

        cvSetImageROI(img , cvRect(pt1.x , pt1.y , pt2.x , pt2.y));


        f =  cvCreateImage( cvGetSize( img) , img->depth , img->nChannels );

        cvCopy(img , f , NULL );

    }


}

cvShowImage("Result" , f );
cvWaitKey(0);
return true;
}



void main()
{
IplImage * img;
hcc = (CvHaarClassifierCascade *)cvLoad(path , 0 , 0 , 0 );
img = cvLoadImage("download.jpg" , 0);
st = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
startDetection(img);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to Opencv, then do not use IplImage, but [cv::Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html). Cropping is trivial using operator parenthesis, and if you need to copy a region of interest in a new image you call clone().

```
cv::Rect roi;
cv::Mat image;
[...] //Initialization of roi and image
cv::Mat roiOfImage = image(roi);
cv::Mat deepCopyOfRoiImage = image(roi).clone();
```

Comment: I wanted to ask how are you doing this :
    cv::Mat roiOfImage = image(roi)

When ever I try to do this it gives me an error